# How to block popups in cefsharp browser in vb.net project/ NOT c sharp

Tags: vb.net, browser, popup, cefsharp

i have been looking for a while now, i have found a solution in csharp , but i couldn't translate it (implement it in my vb.net app).
My only aim is that when the user clicks a link no popups appear.
thank you for your help.
My vb.net coding skill is beginner level, c sharp no knowledge.
the working solution in c sharp:

```
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;

namespace popup_cefsharp
{
    public partial class frm_main : Form
    {
        public frm_main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //variable 
        ChromiumWebBrowser chrome, chrome_popup;

        private void initialize_browser()
        {
            try
            {
                CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
                Cef.Initialize(settings);

                //main browser
                chrome = new ChromiumWebBrowser(this.txt_url.Text.Trim());
                LifespanHandler life = new LifespanHandler();
                chrome.LifeSpanHandler = life;
                life.popup_request += life_popup_request;
                this.pan_container.Controls.Add(chrome);
                chrome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

                //second browser (popup browser)
                chrome_popup = new ChromiumWebBrowser("");
                this.pan_container_popup.Controls.Add(chrome_popup);
                chrome_popup.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error in initializing the browser. Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void carregar_popup_new_browser(string url)
        {
            //open pop up in second browser
            chrome_popup.Load(url);
        }

        private void frm_main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            //close o object cef
            Cef.Shutdown();
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void frm_main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //initialize the browser
            this.initialize_browser();
        }

        private void life_popup_request(string obj)
        {
            //function for open pop up in a new browser
            this.carregar_popup_new_browser(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

[link original post](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1194609/Capturing-a-pop-up-window-using-LifeSpanHandler-an): https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1194609/Capturing-a-pop-up-window-using-LifeSpanHandler-an

Comment: I'm afraid this site is not a code translation service. However, Google will find you many sites that are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally found the solution , if anyone is interested
here is the link, you will need to install the cefsharp nuggets packages, add lifespanhandler as a new class, the file is in the link, then copy the method to call the function from the mainform...
cheers...
https://github.com/messi06/vb.net_CefSharp_popup